# Regex pattern to match and replace a version number in a string c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find replace Version number from a string by using Regex in c#.

string is like this:

string val="AA.EMEA.BizTalk.GroupNettingIntegrations, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a86ac114137740ef";

Is any one can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: That doesn't really make much sense about what you are trying to do, please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Regex will do the replace you are looking for.

```
string val = "AA.EMEA.BizTalk.GroupNettingIntegrations, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a86ac114137740ef";
val = Regex.Replace(val, @"Version=[\d\.]+", "Version=2.0.0.0");
```

EDIT:
You can also use look-behind Regex functionality if you don't want to have to put the "Version=" in the replacement string.  If you are looking for that, add a comment and I'll draw it up.

Comment: val = Regex.Replace(val, @"Version=[\d\.]+", "Version=2.0.0.0");
it should be like this.

Comment: I'd use `(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+)` instead to be more precise for the regular expression. In yours you could allow "2." or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you could easily accomplish this without a regex and have your code be easier to read:

```
 string components[] = someAssemblyFullyQualifiedName.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.IgnoreEmptyEntires);

 if(components.Length > 1)
    components[1] = "Version=2.0.0.0"; // whatever you want to replace with

 string newFullyQualifiedName = string.Join(",", components):
```

Comment: Was going to suggest something similar, you beat me to it (though you dont need to supply the "new char[] { ',' }" bit, just ',' is sufficient)